# NSGraphicsContext currentContext returns nil

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, nsview

This is probably a basic newbie question but I have got stuck on this. Trying to set up Core Plot but have some issues.

By looking at the CPTestApp I am trying just to draw anything but I always get an crash in CPTPlatformSpecificFunctions because the NSGraphicContext is nil.

```
void CPTPushCGContext(CGContextRef newContext)
{
    if ( newContext ) {
        if ( !pushedContexts ) {
            pushedContexts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [pushedContexts addObject:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]];
        [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:newContext flipped:NO]];
    }
}
```

Why does [NSGraphicsContext currentContext] returns nil? I would appreciate any hints. The demo app seems to call the init from the application delegate like me.

EDIT, here is my call to Coreplot:

ApplicationDeletegate.h

```
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *graphHostView;
```

ApplicationDeletegate.m (yes, I know you should not have so much code here)

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupGraph];
}

-(void)setupGraph
{

    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:graphHostView.bounds];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    graphHostView.hostedGraph = graph;

    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainBlackTheme]];
    graph.paddingBottom = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingLeft  = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingTop    = -1.0f;
    graph.paddingRight  = -5.0f;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;

    NSString *title = @"Portfolio Prices: April 23 - 27, 2012";
    graph.title = title;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -16.0f);

}
```

Is awakeFromNib too early? Have I missed something?

Comment: Make sure all interaction with Core Plot happens on the main thread (setup, datasource, etc.). Please post your graph setup code.

Comment: added my super basic setup code.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. What version of Core Plot, Xcode, and OS X are you running?

Comment: I have the same problem running 10.10, Xcode 6 with release-2.0 branch of CorePlot.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe a bug then? I ended up changing the source to Kirks suggestion, so it works but it introduced a couple of issues with sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is no currentContext right now?  You're setting one, so just modify your code to not push if there isn't one.  Verify afterwards that setting it causes currentContext to return the object you set it to.

```
}
NSGraphicsContext *ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
if(ctx != nil) {
    [pushedContexts addObject: ctx];
}
[NSGraph.....
```

Also check your pop to make sure it doesn't do anything dumb if you run out of pushedContexts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That piece of code comes from CorePlot so I assumed that the context was taken care of. Should I create a context? I cannot see anything of creating contexts in the examples.

Comment: It looks like you'd only hit the issue you're describing when you got a context from somewhere and called the CPTPushCGContext function.  How is that used in the example?

Comment: CPTPushCGContext is called deep down in CorePlot code. Never directly called. I am unsure if my problems with the currentContext is related to CorePlot or not.

Comment: This might be an order of operations issue.  Try to do your "setupGraph" code after (some of?) the main view is initialized.

Comment: Seemes to be a bug (https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/137#event-208685686) but this answer helped me to get going.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably making the call outside of the drawRect: call chain. When that happens, even though you get currentContext, the graphicsPort or CGContexts (OS X 10.0 and later) is not set up.

At the view level, call

```
[<view> lockFocus];
<your call to munge the context>
[<view> unlockFocus];
```

where view is the view you are drawing in.